# Can't interact Selenium Chromedriver with Chrome extension made TextArea

Tags: c#, html, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I have a GoogleMeets extension that will help with attendance of persons inside the meet. (It's Google Meet Attendance - https://github.com/al-caughey/Google-Meet-Attendance)

After I open the webpage with selenium webdriver and interact with a icon element to show the **textarea**  when I try to interact with this **textarea** it I get **Exception: Element Not Interactable** or **Cannot set property of 'innerText' of null** when using IJavaScriptExecutor

**NOTE**

Functions names are different because i made a wrapper class around the IWebDriver Object

[image: Loaded Extension UI]

[image: The TextArea zone after I press the Icon button]

<s>[The HTML code of page and TextArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMURZ.png)</s>

The HTML code of page and TextArea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro" dir="ltr"> >

<head>...</head>

<body jscontroller="pjice" jsaction="rcuQ6b: npT2md; click:FAbpgf; auxclick:
Abpgf; mousedown:.CLIENT; keydown:.CLIENT;UjQMac:.CLIENT;WINJic:.CLIENT;PDJFbb:.C
LIENT; AbmZie:.CLIENT; keyup:.CLIENT; keypress:.CLIENT;nHjqDd:.CLIENT; Lhiqec:.CLIE
NT;VSCbUd:.CLIENT;GvneHb:.CLIENT;qakode:.CLIENT" class="EI1Dfe">
    <script aria-hidden="true" nonce>
    window.wiz_progress && window.wiz_progress();
    </script> >
    <div class="MCCOAC IqBFM ecJEib EwZcud cjGgHb d8Etdd LcUz9d" id="yDmHºd" style="bottom: auto; right: auto; width: 1318px; height: 870px;">...</div>
    <div class="MhØNND Mp270b xbg16e mistle" jsaction="click:.CLIENT" style="vi
sibility: visible;">...</div>
    <div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: absolute; top:
-1000px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
    <div id="gma-attendance-fields" data-generate-files="both" class data-auto- add="true">
        <div id="gma-class-list-div"> >
            <p id="gma-class-list-header" class="gma-header" style="display: block;
">...</p> >
            <p id="p-attendance-summary" title="Not Monitoring Attendance!">.</p>
            <textarea id="class-notes" title="If you want to add any notes related
to this class..." placeholder="Enter any notes specific to this clas
S." X/textarea> >
                <p id="invited-list-help" class>...</p>
                <textarea id="invited-list" title="Pick, paste or type your class list
into this field" placeholder="Your class list goes here.
Click the blue question mark below for help." classx</textarea> == $0 >
                    <div id="ema-class-list-buttons" class></div>
```

### CODE

```cs
public void start_bot()
{
    this.setDriverTimeout(60);
    if (this.driver.WindowHandles.Count > 1)
    {
        this.driver.SwitchTo().Window(this.driver.WindowHandles[1]);
    }


    try
    {
        IWebElement classroom = this.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='class-list-edit']");
        //classroom = this.findElementByXPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/p[1]/select");
        while (!classroom.Enabled && !classroom.Displayed)
        {
            classroom = this.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='class-list-edit']");
        }

        classroom.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        classroom = this.findElementByClassName("being-editted");

       // this.driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('textarea.being-eddited').innerText='Deoanca Rares'");

      
        classroom.SendKeys("John Doe");
        Console.WriteLine("Found Element");
       // IJavaScriptExecutor js = new IJavaScriptExecutor();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        IWebElement classroom = this.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='class-list-edit']");
        while (!classroom.Enabled && !classroom.Displayed)
        {
            classroom = this.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='class-list-edit']");
        }

        classroom.Click();

       // classroom = this.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='invited - list']");
        classroom = this.findElementByClassName("being-editted");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        classroom.Click();
        classroom.SendKeys("John Doe");
        Console.WriteLine("Found Element");
    }
}
```

Comment: The first two images are good screenshots so I edited your question to display them instead. The third imageis HTML code. Please [edit] your question to include the HTML as a code block rather than an image. Images are to difficult to read code with.